# How to convert any date format in milliseonds in linux/centos/rhel with shell script

Tags: linux, milliseconds

How to convert any date format in milliseonds in linux/centos/rhel with shell script

Date formats like:
Thu, 23 Jun 2022 08:27:26 +0000,
Thu Jun 23 11:11:43 UTC 2022,
2022-06-23T08:28:23Z

Answer (score 1):

This can be converted in milliseconds with command:

```
date -d "2022-06-23T08:28:23Z" +"%s%N"
```

Any other format of date can also be converted with above command like:

```
date -d "Thu, 23 Jun 2022 08:27:26 +0000" +"%s%N"
date -d "Thu Jun 23 11:11:43 UTC 2022" +"%s%N"
```

Comment: Actually "milliseconds" would need `date -d "Thu Jun 23 11:11:43 UTC 2022" +"%s%03N"`